# How to give line break between two strings in single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have used single column to store multiple comments . In that column i have to store every comments in new line so that i can able to differentiate the comments.
I have tried CHAR(13) and CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) between two strings . But it's not working.I shown the records in single line.

**Tried code:**

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(100)
SET @text = 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13) + 'This is line 2.'
SELECT @text
```

Please suggest the solution.

[image]

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c4a1c06ef37fadbb1188cb387c9e61e9 its working

Comment: It's not working. you tested in which version management studio?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin for your reference i have attached image in query

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PRINT` statement instead of `SELECT` statement to achieve what you want.

For example, you can use any of the followings:

```
PRINT 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13) + 'This is line 2.'
```

Or

```
PRINT 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
```

Or

```
PRINT CONCAT(N'This is line 1.', 0xd000a, N'This is line 2.')
```

---

**UPDATE:** According to [this forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c4257e88-87db-4d2b-8a5e-fd27c4c413ff/how-to-add-new-line-in-select-statement?forum=transactsql),

> You can not see char(13) in SSMS in the Grid format. This character is there and you can see it if you output the result into report, into text, into Excel. But in SSMS grid you can not see this character.

You can change settings from "Results to Grid" to "Results to Text"
 from menu using the following steps:

**Query -> Results to -> Results to Text**

Then you will be able to view line break between two strings using any of the followings

```
SELECT 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13) + 'This is line 2.'
```

Or

```
SELECT 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
```

Or

```
SELECT CONCAT(N'This is line 1.', 0xd000a, N'This is line 2.')
```

Comment: Yes we can use , But the result we will not get in table format right..

Comment: @Gopal I have updated the answer according to your comment. Please check it.

Comment: i have one query. Is it possible to view linebreak while Result in Grid format?

Comment: According to best of my knowledge, I think it is not possible.

Comment: @Gopal, grid format will not show line breaks (which should be CR/LF not just CR or LF in Windows). However, you can preserve those during copy/paste of grid results. From the SSMS menu, Query Options-->Results-->Grid-->Retain CR/LF on copy or save.

Answer (score 0):

another way

```
select concat(N'This is line 1.', 0xd000a, N'This is line 2.')
```

or

```
select 'This is line 1.' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + 'This is line 2.'
```

Comment: @Gopal try 2nd one

Comment: @Gopal https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d482621ec25ce37760e088f2db2663b4 check this link

Comment: about code not working in SQL server management studio 2017..
Record stored in single line.